# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to `int[][]' while initializing int array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create an int array of arrays as follows:

```
int[][] results = new int[3][3];
```

I keep getting this compiler error: "error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to`int[][]'"

I can create a single dimension (int[]) or multi dimensional array (int[3,3]) without issue. I'm following the documentation on MSDN and elsewhere. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
int[][] results = new int[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; i++)
    results[i] = new int[3];
```